# Parse JSON request in Nodejs using Express Framework

Tags: node.js, express

How can we parse JSON request data (POST Method) from Express? Here is a sample JSON request:

```
{
  "username": "nodejs",
  "password": "123"
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/parse-json-in-javascript

Answer (score -1):

If you have body parser module, you can draw the requested variables in body

with req.body.~~

for example, like this:

```
funciton(res, req){
    var username = req.body.username; //save the requested variable in username variable
    return res.send(username);
}
```

the result would be:

```
nodejs
```

Comment: Tried this with Express 4x version but still not working